# Php array is destroyed and replaced each time I make an ajax request to it?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

At the click of a button an ajax POST is made to my php script which has the following code

```
<?php
    $number = $_POST["id"];
    $myarray[$number] = $_POST["marker"];
?>
```

The two POST entries are `id` and `marker`. I was hoping that each click of the button by the end user would construct an increasingly larger array called `$myarray`, because `$number` usually changes.

Instead what happens is each click of the button destroys the original `$myarray` and creates a new `$myarray` with only one data pair (the newly sent $number and `$_POST["marker"]`).

How can I code it so the array is built up with each click of the button?

Answer (score 4):

HTTP is a stateless protocol, so there is no way for the server to know about `$my_array` after each request. PHP just generates some HTML and the server serves that generated HTML.
You could store the info on the client side in javascript, though.

As for your comment-question:
No, it wouldn't. The solution really depends on your use case, if you need information to be available for later use, you'd have to store it in a database or file. If only for the current browsing page, store it in the user's browser with javascript. Storing it as session variable is another option.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that. I've done some quick googling, would setting the array as a global variable or super global variable get around this issue? If so how would I go about it?

Comment: I understand. In that case I will store the information in a cookie and update the cookie with each button click and pregmatch. The information is not sensitive, it is just user preferences on the page.

Comment: @James Nope (answer to your first comment). Global variables are also bound within the session, they die at the end of it. If you don't want to go with JS, you could try storing your data in [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) varialbes

Comment: @James (second comment) Cookies as a solution to your scenario are applicable, and $_SESSION is related to cookies (read the manual). Anyways you could go with cookies if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store it in a session.  [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Basically,

```
session_start();

$myarray = $_SESSION['myarray'];
//work with $myarray here

//store it back in the session
$_SESSION['myarray'] = $myarray;
```

Answer (score 0):

push the data onclick using javascript. Then try to pass the whole queue on each click